# Update data to file each amount of bytes

Tags: java, android

I want to write my content data to a file each 10kb of file. It looks like this:
[image]

What I tried:

```
 FileInputStream is;
 FileOutputStream out;
 File input = new File(filePath);
 int fileLength = input.length();
 int len = 0;
    while (len < fileLength){
        len += is.read(buff);
        // write my data
        out.write(data, 0, data.length);
       // how to move is to read next 10kb???
    }
```

I wonder is there anyway to move the cursor reader to next amount of bytes? Or do I miss anything?

**Update**:Thank to `@DThought`, here is my implementation:

```
    File input = new File(filePath);
    long fileLength = input.length();
    byte[] data;
    byte[] buff = new byte[data.length];
    long JUMP_LENGTH = 10 * 1024;
    RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile(input, "rw");

    long step = JUMP_LENGTH + data.length;
    for (long i = 0; i < fileLength; i += step) {
        // read to buffer
        raf.seek(i);
        raf.read(buff);

        raf.seek(i); // make sure it move to correct place after reading
        raf.write(data);

    }

    raf.close();
```

And it worked well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html RandomAccessFile instead of FileOutputStream.

This will enable you to seek to arbitary positions

```
byte[] data=new byte[1024];
RandomAccessFile file=new RandomAccessFile(new File("name"),"rw");
file.seek(10*1024);
file.write(data);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can write empty array or spaces to that specific portion for example,as you can't jump to specific memory of file and can't avoid `10KB`.

***FOR EXAMPLE***

```
    OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(new File("D:/a.txt"));
    byte[] emptyByte=new byte[10*1024];
    Arrays.fill(emptyByte, " ".getBytes()[0]);//Empty array
    os.write(yourData,0,yourData.length-1);
    os.write(emptyByte,0,emptyByte.length-1);
    //Write after each data to leave space of 10KB
```

***NOTE*** *I don't know how exactly set it for `10KB`* and other than that it is just an example,you can use it for yours.I have added spaces in that portion of file.You can achieve it according to your requirements.*I think you can't directly jump to specific memory address but you can fill it with empty data.*

---

I guess [`#seek`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html#seek%28long%29) method of `RandomAccessFile` may also help you as suggested by `DThought`,on this but it is *measured from the beginning of this file* so kindly note that.